# Read JSON file without using external libraries (update using only org.json)

Tags: java, json

i have an assignement where i have to read a json file containing elections information  and save the data i get. The problem is i can't use any external libraries like simple json etc. The proffessor sugested i did something like this:

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(new File(filename));
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(fin);
JSONObject elections = new JSONObject(tokener);

JSONArray candidates = elections.getJSONArray("candidates"); JSONArray
ballots = elections.getJSONArray("ballots");
```

Then i could access my candidates with

```
candidates.getString(i)
```

And my ballots with

```
JSONArray ballot = ballots.getJSONArray(i)
```

But when i run the code i get the following exception :

```
org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 6 [character 1 line 6]
at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:433)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:194)
at Schulze.main(Schulze.java:17)
```

The exception comes from this line of code :

```
JSONObject elections = new JSONObject(tokener);
```

The json files content is something like this :

> {    "candidates": [
>          "a", "b", "c", "d"    ],    "ballots": [
>          [0, 2, 3, 1],
>          [0, 2, 3, 1],
>          [0, 2, 3, 1],
>          [0, 2, 3, 1],
>          [0, 2, 3, 1],
>          [0, 2, 3, 1],
>
> ```
>    [1, 0, 3, 2],
>    [1, 0, 3, 2],
>    [1, 0, 3, 2],
>    [1, 0, 3, 2],
>
>    [2, 3, 1, 0],
>    [2, 3, 1, 0], 
>    [2, 3, 1, 0],
>
>    [3, 1, 0, 2],
>    [3, 1, 0, 2], 
>    [3, 1, 0, 2],
>    [3, 1, 0, 2],        
>
>    [3, 2, 1, 0],
>    [3, 2, 1, 0],        
>    [3, 2, 1, 0],
>    [3, 2, 1, 0]    ] }
> ```

Any ideas on what might be the problem here?

Comment: can you show us the json content?

Comment: I don't know. The proffessor won't let me.

Comment: Is the json valid? Can you show us the json?

Comment: "not any external library"? Then why is there org.json code in there?

Comment: @fge I was telling myself that...

Comment: If you want to parse something (or help about parsing something), you need to see what it looks like. Please post the JSON you try to read, or at least part of it.

Comment: @fge no other external library except org.json

Comment: If anyone's wondering still, that JSON is valid

Comment: Your teacher really doesn't help; (s)he allows you to use one JSON library and it's the worst of them all :/

Answer (score 1):

A json file is still a normal text file. You can ignore org.json and read the file with normal Java code that deals with text files. This won't require any external libraries.

Comment: Then the title of the question is wrong. I updated it for your. Please review